# How to make first blog post in full width (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

I hope someone here can help me answering this question?
Is it possible to choose the format of a post in Wordpress? I would love to have the opportunity to show the first post (and single-post) in full width depending on what format the image have (horizontal/vertical)?

Hope my question makes sense?

My blog is http://thelocals.dk

Answer (score 1):

I used this plugin to accomplish a similar task. [Single Post Template](http://wordpress.org/plugins/single-post-template/)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Would that affect the single post only or the frontpage/homepage as well?